# Spring MVC API call gets CORS error only when calling from Angular. Calling the API from Java works fine though

Tags: angular, spring, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have my API, which is written in Java Spring MVC, being hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. When I call my API from an Angular app being run locally on my computer, I get a CORS error saying that it needs the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I ran an Options request in Postman to see if maybe my CORS implementation doesn't work on the preflight Options request. I could see all the right headers:

[image: picture is linked since I don't post much on here]

So now I'm completely lost as to what to do. I keep getting CORS errors when calling the API, which is on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I would love to hear any ideas as to what to try. Perhaps it's something with Elastic Beanstalk.

Edit: I tried making the API call in Java and it worked fine, so this appears to be an Angular problem. Anyone else have ever had a CORS issue when making a call *from* Angular in particular? I'm running my Angular application locally on a Macbook Pro if that matters.

Comment: Have a look at this article about it: https://keepgrowing.in/java/springboot/fix-cors-issues-between-spring-boot-and-angular-on-localhost/

Comment: @alex87 Thank you for the reply! I had already set up another way to get CORS allowed, however I still tried that method just in case. Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: Ah sorry, cors can be a pain. Especially when you're not using https.

Comment: @alex87 will using https help solve my problem? That is definitely an option for me

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't using the angular proxy? https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: @Cyril From what I've read, and I could be wrong, it's only good when you are running both the backend and frontend from localhost. If that's not that case and it can work for me with the frontend being ran locally and backend being on AWS EB, I'll definitely give that a shot though

Comment: @memeboi27 You can proxy to any url. I have used it with backends running on remote servers.

Comment: @memeboi27 See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards You cannot use the wildcard (`*`) if you allow credentialed requests.

Comment: @jub0bs ah, that just might be the problem! I’ll have to try it when I get home.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add cros configuration in your Srping mvc application to see does it solve your problem. If you use spring boot, you can add cors configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(CorsConfiguration.ALL,"null")
                        .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have already added CORS configuration. I even can see all the necessary CORS headers when I do an Options request (equivalent of preflight request) in Postman. However, when I try it in my Angular app, it still gives me CORS issues on the same URL.

Comment: have you add cors config for you angular app, some says add configurations like this may solve the problem : ```angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers
.common['X-Requested-With'];
}); ```

Comment: @william0754 Allowing the `null` origin with credentials is strongly discouraged for security reasons.